# AVCaptureSessionPresets (Photo/High/Med/Low): specific image resolution per device type?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, avcapturesession

I have a Universal photo type app in dev (iOS5+) and would like to offer the user the option to set the default image resolution, giving them some feedback as to image dimensions and the approximate file size per image. Since there are now so many devices with different camera capabilities, and different capabilities between front and back cameras on a device, this seems somewhat complicated.

Specifically:

- Am I wrong in assuming that these presets vary by camera capability
  per device (e.g. the sucky iPad 2 front camera "Photo" res is going
  to yield an image of smaller dimensions than an iPhone 4G
- How can I determine the image sizes of `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`,
  `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`, etc. per camera (by device, front +
  back). If I know the size I can make a guess as to file size with a
  given compression.